# How do I get data in it into a list with a map inside it? Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
final List<Map<String, Object>> _li = [
{
    'm1':Scaffold(
     //    appBar: AppBar(title: Text('woow2')),
      body: Container(
            child:  Text('woow'),
          )
          
),
'al':"as",
},
{
    'm12':Scaffold(
  //    appBar: AppBar(title: Text('woow2')),
      body: Container(
            child:  Text('woow'),
          )),
          'al':"zzz",
},
];
```

Answer (score 0):

On your `_li` it contains scaffolds which is scary while you can just communicate using variables like passing string of tittle and text.

In your case, the answer snippet will be like this(for 1st widget)

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: _li[0]["m1"] is Widget
          ? _li[0]["m1"] as Widget
          : const Scaffold(body: Text("error widget")),
    );
  }
}}
}
```

You need to maintain `_li` index and map key.

Comment: body: _li[0]['a'] , This is a wrong line, not a condition that I want - this is a strange mistake

Comment: Note that adding 0 variables but without a variable or with a variable gives me an error

Comment: Can you clarify the question of what exactly you are trying to archive and what went wrong. Check more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I want to fetch a page with a key

Comment: you are using `List<Map>` and  to get widget I've used `_li[0]["m1"]` which means 1st index item key `m1`

Comment: This is wrong, not normal, wrong body:_li[_dd]["m1"] ,

Comment: This is a mistake, not a normal mistake

Comment: Are you referring to my answer is not normal mistake?  `body:_li[0]["m1"] as Widget`  will  work